# Создание нового столбца при совпадении части значения из одного столбца со значением из другого

Tags: r

У меня есть датасет `df1`:

```
    X1  X2
    1   12345678
    2   400454
    3   12345214
    4   77753523
    5   77753827
```

И есть датасет `df2`:

```
    X1  X2  X3
    1   123 1
    2   125 5
    3   400 2
    4   643 3
    5   423 4
    6   765 5
    7   213 6
    8   124 2
    9   777 9
    10  432 1
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в `df1` появился 3 столбец - `df1$X3` со значениями соответствующими значениям `df2$X3`, при условии совпадения части значения из `df1$X2` со значением `df2$X2`. Так должен выглядеть `df1`:

```
    X1  X2          X3
    1   12345678    1
    2   400454      2
    3   12345214    1
    4   77753523    9
    5   77753827    9
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Совпадение частей значений любых ? Или именно ведущие три цифры/символа ?

Comment: @YuryArrow Спасибо за ответ. "Ключ" в реальной задаче может находиться не в начале и иметь разную длину. То есть да, интересует совпадение любой части, а не первых 3 цифр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле - в вашей постановке задача не определена конкретно. А что будете делать если строка совпадет сразу с несколькими ключами ?

Векторно решить задачу быстро не могу придумать как. Вот, можно перебором создать таблицу связности. Соответственно - решение очень сильно будет зависеть от контекста в котором данная задача будет использоваться. Если одноразовый отчет сделать это одно. А если на production такое ставить - я бы свое решение не стал использовать... (Создание источников надо взять из предыдущего ответа)

```
df_links <- data.frame(valkey=NA, val=NA, spr_key=NA, spr_val=NA, spr_val_2=NA, links=NA)
df_links <- df_links[-1,]

for (i in 1:nrow(df1))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2))
  {
    df_links <- rbind(df_links, data.frame
                      (
                      valkey=df1[i,1],
                      val=df1[i,2],
                      spr_key=df2[j,1],
                      spr_val=df2[j,2],
                      spr_val_2=df2[j,3],
                      links=grepl(pattern=df2[j,2], x=df1[i,2], fixed=TRUE)
                      ))
  }  
}

  print(df_links[df_links$links==TRUE,c(1,2,5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  x1=rep(1:5),
  x2=c(12345678,400454,12345214,77753523,77753827)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x1=rep(1:10),
  x2=c(123,125,400,643,423,765,213,124,777,432),
  x3=c(1,5,2,3,4,5,6,2,9,1)
)  
###########################################################
# Создадим ключ
df1$key <- substr(df1[,2],1,3)
df2$key <- df2$x2

# Мерджим таблицы
df1 <- merge(df1,df2[,c('key','x3')], by='key')

# Удалим ключ
df1 <- df1[ , !(names(df1) %in% "key")]
df2 <- df2[ , !(names(df2) %in% "key")]

print(df1)
```